# Preventing image from rendering in AngularJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have this jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/HMZuh/1/

Which contains this html

```
<div ng-app ng:controller="ShowHideController">
    <div ng-show='showMe'>
        <img ng-src="{{imageSource}}"/>
    </div>
    <button ng-click='showImage()'> show image </button>
<div>
```

and this script:

```
function ShowHideController($scope) {
    $scope.showMe = false;

    $scope.imageSource = '';

    $scope.showImage = function(){
        $scope.showMe = true;
        $scope.imageSource = 'https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png';
    }
}
```

I'm getting a 404, image not found when the source has not yet been set, is there any way of preventing this when showMe is false?

​

Comment: Not having this problem - wondering if it's a browser issue.  What browser are you trying this with?

Comment: I tried it on chrome and firefox - both latest versions

Comment: Sorry mate, tried this on a local project from scratch, never got the 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I improved on this by using ui-if from http://angular-ui.github.com/
Instead of hiding/showing using ng-hide/ng-show, ui-if simply does not render the element.

```
<div ui-hide='ImageHasBeenUploaded'>
    <img ng-src='/some/image/path/{{imageName}}/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this you can:

1. Use `ng-repeat` http://jsfiddle.net/bGA4T/
2. Use [$compile](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24compile) and declare your own directive
3. Write your own `ng-src` directive
4. ...

I think there are many ways to solve this.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using ng-repeat which 'solved' the issue. Not quite what I would have liked, but it worked=)