# AngularJs + JqueryUI slider initial values

Tags: jquery-ui, angularjs, angularjs-directive

this is my first post here, so I hope it will be comprehensive.

I'm using AngularJs and I've added a JqueryUI slider using an angular directive.
I've found a lot of examples on how to do that, but none of them show me ho to add the initial values to the slider, from the scope.

Here is a  [jsfiddle I'created](http://jsfiddle.net/ntaUJ/21/)

```
var testApp= angular.module('testApp',['ngResource']);

testApp.factory('remoteRequest', function($resource) {
var remoteRequest = $resource('/echo/json/');
return remoteRequest;
});

testApp.directive('sliderDays', function() {
return {
    link: function(scope, elem,attrs) {
        $(elem).slider({
            range: true,
            min: scope.days[1],
            max: scope.days[scope.days.length-1],
            values: [scope.days[0], scope.days[1]],
            slide: function( event, ui ) {
                console.log(ui.values[ 0 ] +" "+ ui.values[ 1 ]                 );
            }
        });
    }
}
});

function TestCtrl($scope, $resource, remoteRequest)
{
$scope.prova=1;
$scope.days=[];
var ret= remoteRequest.get(function(){
     $scope.days=[1,2,3,4,5,10,25];
});
}
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working fiddle from you code, I added comments at places I changed. One main problem you had was that you were trying to access array elements from `scope.days` before it had any data.

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/ntaUJ/24/

**View**

```
<div ng-app="testApp">
    <div ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        <p><span>{{days[0]}}</span> - <span>{{days[days.length-1]}}</span></p>
        <div slider-days days="days"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Code**

```
var testApp= angular.module('testApp',['ngResource']);

testApp.directive('sliderDays', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, elem,attrs) {
      $(elem).slider({
        range: true,
        min: scope.days[1],
        max: scope.days[scope.days.length-1],
        values: [scope.days[0], scope.days[scope.days.length-1]],
        slide: function( event, ui ) {
          console.log(ui.values[0], ui.values[1]);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});

function TestCtrl($scope)
{
    $scope.days=[1,2,3,4,5,10,25];
}
```

Comment: Ok, but wath if I need to load data after a remote request, as I've done in my example? There is another way or I simply mistunderstood the usage of that kind of directive?

Comment: The digest cycles of angular should update the information you send to your directive. You just need to add some programming checks. You can also look at setting up a two-way data binding isolated scope for the directive such as `scope: {days: "="}` (check out http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive for more info on that). If its a one time call for the data, you can resolve that information which will make it so you have the data before the view is rendered (more info here on that here http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$routeProvider  (look for the resolve property))

Comment: I solved using "ui-if" controller with angular-ui, like specified in this post, [link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12353549/preventing-image-from-rendering-in-angularjs
Thank you!